# Present webpage vertically for Google Cast / Chrome Cast

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries, chromecast, google-cast

I opened a new tab in Chrome and loaded our dashboard then used:

```
document.body.style.setProperty("-webkit-transform", "rotate(-90deg)", null);
```

Here is the result

[image]

It is possible to set the viewport to correctly match the TV?